I want to change default electron icon but not able to do that
Here is my package json file cdde.
"build": {
    "linux": {
      "target": "deb",
      "category": "Office",
      "icon": "./src/assets/icons/256x256.png"
    },
   
  }

And here is my main.js/electron.js code.

function createWindow() {
  
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, '../src/assets/icons/256x256.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webSecurity: false,
    },
  });

}




I have tried a lot of things but nothing is working.

I am pretty sure the icon is not visible on some browser if it is stored locally. For ex: chrome never shows it on localhost

Did you try putting your customized icons inside the build/ folder? As far as i know, build folder should contain the default icon files. Maybe you can also try replacing those files.
From: https://www.electron.build/icons
""
Linux
Linux icon set will be generated automatically based on the macOS icns file or common icon.png.
Or you can put them into the build/icons directory if you want to specify them yourself. The filename must contain the size (e.g. 256x256.png) of the icon). Recommended sizes: 16, 32, 48, 64, 128, 256 (or just 512).
""
Note: There is also another possible solution using electron-packager + electron-installer-debian but since you are trying with electron-builder, this solution might not be suitable for you.

I am new at electron.
here is my code.
code of my electron.js file.
const win = new BrowserWindow({
width: 1200,
height: 800,
icon: "../build/icons/256x256.png",
webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true,
webSecurity: false,
},
});
Json:
"linux": {
"target": "deb",
"category": "Office",
"icon": "./build/icons/256x256.png"
},
Can please let me know what i can do?
